# Possible endings in Metal Gear Solid V: TPP

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

How many endings are there in MGS 5: TPP?

Are they exclusive, meaning that when I get one ending I need to replay the game to get the other or is it possible to see all of them in one playthrough?

If it is possible, then (as spoiler-free as possible), what are the requirements for each ending? I didn't want to read any Wiki's as they often contain too many spoilers.

The endings I've heard about are:

1. Huey's ending
2. Quiet's ending
3. "True" ending (whatever this means)

Comment: I added the [spoiler] to the heading due to the fact possible answers from any users could generate spoilers no matter how big or small

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Huey's ending requires you to finish Huey's storyline. This just entails you doing gold-marked Side Ops, namely the one(s) involving the AI Pod.

Quiet's ending is similar, but to get the last two missions to end her story you have to have the maximum Bond rating with her and do Mission 43. If you have the "Butterfly" emblem part equipped as the emblem for Diamond Dogs, then her ending will be stalled until you remove the "Butterfly" emblem. You must continue using the "Butterfly" emblem part to prevent Quiet's ending, otherwise it will happen after a chain of unstoppable events next time you autosave without the "Butterfly" equipped.

- From what I have observed of other in game events, if you complete
  mission 43 without having max Bond level with Quiet, you can re do
  the mission again later when you have max Bond level and it will
  work. For instance you can choose to kill Quiet during your first
  encounter with her in Chapter 1, but if you re do the mission and
  don't kill her then Quiet will join your company like normal. Someone
  correct me if this event has some kind of weird exception.

"True" ending is kind of vague, but I assume that you are referring to Mission 46. You have to complete all gold-marked Main Ops, Side Ops and listen to all gold-marked cassette tapes to unlock Mission 46.

There is another ending that was datamined from the game's files, and obviously unfinished. Google "MGSV disarmament ending" if you want to know more about that.

None of these endings are mutually exclusive since the game is structured in a sandbox like MGS:PW.

Comment: Quiet's ending also requires you do not use a specific emblem part (the butterfly) during mission 43, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @twobugs: The Butterfly emblem locks Quiet in so she cannot leave DD. Clearly, if you need her to leave, then do not use the emblem.

Comment: I'm trying to be intentionally vague to not spoil anything. You may want to delete your comment, but thank you for confirming.

Comment: Just to clear things up - if I finish mission 43 with her at lower bond level the ending will not trigger and I will not be able to retrigger it later?

Comment: You're mixing up the Butterfly *emblem part* and the Butterfly *codename*. To stop Quiet from leaving, you need to customize your emblem to use the Butterfly *emblem part* and keep it equipped. You only need to get the Butterfly code name once to be able to use the Butterfly emblem part.

Comment: Oh, really? I misinterpreted that from the research I did. I did not think you actually had to change your emblem, that seems kind of bizarre. @Asunez From what I have observed of other in game events, if you complete mission 43 without having max Bond level with Quiet, you can re do the mission again later when you have max Bond level and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The endings are not multiple choice or dependent on anything but you finishing all the missions. Thus, if you play all the missions, you will get all the endings.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know Quiet's ending changes depending on your bond level with her or something...

Comment: @Asunez: I am not aware of that but could be wrong.